# FAQ: My question was closed, in my opinion wrongly. What do I do?

Tags: discussion, faq

My question was closed by users/moderators and I think that it deserved to stay open. What am I supposed to do now? What could I do? And what should I not do?

[Return to FAQ index](https://linguistics.meta.stackexchange.com/q/344/111)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### What am I supposed to do? What could I do?

If you honestly think your question was closed wrongly and that it should be reopened, your best bet is Meta. Some suggestions:

- Don't just post a rant, that won't help you (as in any other situation in life);
- Write constructively about why you think it should have stayed open, the reasons. Expose them in your question in a clear manner. That alone will grant you more positive attention even if we don't agree.
- If it turns out that your question deserved to be closed, accept it and move on. It happens to everybody sooner or later, nothing to be angry about: life is too short for this kind of stuff. In turn, ask if and how you could improve it, the community will certainly help. Alternatively, if nothing works out, consider posting in the Chat: there you can talk about anything that might not work here.

### What should I not do?

If you seriously want your question to be reopened, don't act immaturely. Don't insult moderators or fellow users: they don't deserve it and that's only going to ruin your chances (even in the case you truly had). It's not going to help you. It never helped other users. No reason to make it worse.

Also, don't go serially downvoting other people's posts just because they closed your question: actions must be taken **on the posts** and **not on the users**. We are not judging you by closing your question, we are judging your question. Not to mention that this will be seen, your serial downvoting reversed and your account probably suspended; **that's not worth it**. Besides, even moderators get their question closed sometimes; and yes, they stay closed sometimes.

Moderators and other users, all of us are human beings, and as such, **we all make mistakes**. So, yes, we can close a question wrongly. We're not robots. If you seriously think a moderator is abusing the powers, email the team using the link you find at the bottom of the page. Remember, however, that normally, moderators do what they think is right. Unless they're abusing, moderators do what they are supposed to do: moderate.

But when it happens that your question gets closed, don't post rants in the comments and then disappear. Your question will be deleted sooner or later if you don't do something about it, so why not give it a try and fix it? [Closure is not a permanent state, but it's up to you](https://linguistics.meta.stackexchange.com/q/248/111) if it'll be or not. We can certainly help and many of us will, but you must be the first to help yourself.